# error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'data1'

Tags: c++, c

I am unable to understand why the compiler is giving error in below case. Please help.

### test.h: part of C++ project

```
using namespace std;
extern "C"
{
    #include "testc.h" 
}

class test
{
    private:
    public:
    work    data1; /*<-- Getting error here*/
    work    data2; */<-- Getting error here*/

    test();
};
```

### testc.h: part of C project

```
typedef struct
{
    int x;
}work;
```

Comment: [Couldn't reproduce](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/a1gCxJvoyjvQNwBI9) with the `#include` expanded and the comment fixed.

Comment: @user1667704 post the error and what compiler you are using

Comment: @asalic: MSVC 10.0 and error same as issue heading

Comment: @juanchopanza....corrected now

Comment: Works fine here after comment  had been corrected.

Comment: @Neel Can you fix the comment now?

Comment: @MikeCAT your link gives *500 — Internal Server Error*

Comment: @Default Sorry I made a typo. http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/a1gCxJvoyjvQNwBI

Comment: have you tried `::work` instead, maybe it is a scoping issue?

Comment: I suspect that you have more code than that, and that there's possibly some more error messages before the one you're quoting.